# Vuejs - Why does the trigger of a method also trigger an unrelated method via v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have created a component that does two things.

Feature 1: toggling a button cycles between a blue square and a red square.

Feature 2: inputting 5 or more characters in an input area reveals a green square.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="container1">
      <h2>Container 1</h2>
      <h5>Toggle Button to Change Box</h5>
      <div class="box1" v-if="isBlueBoxDisplayed()">
        <span>1a</span>
      </div>
      <div class="box2" v-else>
        <span>1b</span>
      </div>
      <button @click="toggleBlueBox">Toggle Blue Box</button>
    </div>
    <div id="container2">
      <h2>Container 2</h2>
      <h5>Type 5 or more characters for Green Box</h5>
      <input
        placeholder="Type 5 characters"
        v-model="userInput"
        @input="validateInputForGreenBox()"
      />
      <div class="box3" v-if="displayGreen">
        <span>2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container3">
      <p>
        Why does <span class="bold">isBlueBoxDisplayed()</span> method trigger
        when <span class="bold">validateInput()</span> is triggered?
      </p>
      <p>(see console for confirmation of this)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      displayBlue: false,
      displayGreen: false,
      userInput: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleBlueBox() {
      this.displayBlue = !this.displayBlue;
    },
    isBlueBoxDisplayed() {
      console.log("isBlueBoxDisplayed() method activated!");
      if (this.displayBlue) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    },
    validateInputForGreenBox() {
      console.log("validateInputForGreenBox() method Hit!");
      if (this.userInput.length > 4) {
        return (this.displayGreen = true);
      }
      this.displayGreen = false;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```
<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

#container1,
#container2 {
  border-right: 2px solid grey;
}

div > span {
  color: white;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: 600;
}
.box1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.box3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
</style>
```

Sandbox here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-matsumoto-lq2mj?file=/src/App.vue

**The issue:**

The two features have nothing to do with one another. And yet, when a user types into the input area (which triggers the **validateInputForGreenBox()** method, as it should) it triggers the **isBlueBoxDisplayed()** method (which should not be triggered).

On a large scale application that I have, this is causing some performance issues whereby multiple unrelated methods are being triggered. So why is this happening? And is there something that can be done so that unrelated methods don't trigger?

Comment: It's likely because it's evaluating the truthiness of that method call each time *any* change happens on the page. Just part of Vue's reactivity I guess, not too sure though

Answer (score 2):

Although a simple answer, I've seen the struggle many times.

The issue here is that the functions that you pass to your events are being called immediately, almost as acting as an IIFE. Because of the existence of `v-if` on the page, you're causing a reflow which is triggering the methods again.

Short answer:

Don't use `()` when passing functions to events:

Good:

```
@input="validateInputForGreenBox"
```

Bad:

```
@input="validateInputForGreenBox()"
```

[and the fiddle for proof](https://jsfiddle.net/jp47ntr6/)

Comment: I was writing the same answer UP from me.

Comment: in your fiddle the button for blue box doesnt work. I think in this case you should use computed property instead of method

Comment: Well this is all well and good, thank you. But a follow up: what if we need to pass arguments into the function? Say for example the function is attached to a list item, and we want to pass into the function the index of that list item. In that case I would have to do this: @input="validateInputForGreenBox(index)".

Comment: Just testing your fiddle, and the isBlueBoxDisplayed in your fiddle doesn't toggle the blue/red box anymore. I guess because you removed the (). Is there any way to get that working again, while keeping your answer correct?